# How can I hide/remove a subview by default when it's superview loaded but still have access to it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7, uitextfield

I have a view which displays a UILabel and UITextField subviews as well as an UIImageView and 2 UIButtons. These all make up a form. One of the fields is dedicated to date entry in dd/mm//yyyy format.

I decided to create another view (called datePickerView) inside my main view which holds a UIDatePicker instance. When the date field on the form mentioned above is clicked this view with the datepicker is show. Upon clicking the done button the view is hidden/removed again.

I have methods that deal with the showing and hiding of this view:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *datePickerView;
- (void) hidePickerView {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [[self datePickerView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -250, 320, 50)];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [[self datePickerView] removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}

- (void) showPickerView {
    [[self view] addSubview:[self datePickerView]];
    [[self datePickerView] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, -250, 320, 50)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         [[self datePickerView] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 260)];
                     }];
}
```

I call these methods in my `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` UITextField delegate methods.

My problem is the the view with the datepicker is visible when it's superview is first loaded. I tried dragging this datepicker view to the top of the hierarchy above all the textfields and buttons but this only shifts the view behind them.

I've also tried hiding the view through storyboard interface, tried adding a hide method to viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear. The methods I tested were:

```
[self datePickerView] removeFromSuperview];
[[self datePickerView] setHidden:YES];
[self hidePickerView];
```

These hide the datePickerView no problem but when I click the textfield the datePickerView doesn't show.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // missing since date field error checking
    if (textField == [self missingSinceField]) {
        [self showPickerView];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == [self missingSinceField]) {
        [self hidePickerView];
    }
}
```

When I don't hide or remove the datePickerView in any way shape or form and tap it the datePickerView is loaded no problem.

** Just before posting this question I set a breakpoint in my showDatePicker method and when I uncomment `[self datePickerView] removeFromSuperview];` I see that my datePickerView outlet is nil so this may explain why I'm having the issue I'm having. Commenting it again and trying again shows it as not being nil.

I think this is what's wrong but not sure how to make sure when viewDidLoad is run that my datePickerView isn't nil. I can't have it showing in the background of the form under the text fields and I don't think changing the colour of it to white so users can't see it isn't elegant.

Help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your IBOutlet property for `datePickerView` is `weak`, so, when you remove it from the superview it gets destroyed.

Either make it `strong`, or use the `hidden` property instead (remembering to set `hidden` to `NO` in `showPickerView` and `YES` in `hidePickerView` - where you currently add and remove the view).

Comment: This works and I create a new action connected to a "done" button on the datepicker page with similar code to the hidePickerView. The thing is the second time round it doesn't seem to work. It loads the date picker view but it now looks like it's in the background.

Comment: Yea I'm using the setHidden and also have set the datepickerview to strong. I tried bringsubviewtofront and it makes no difference. Datepickerview never comes back to the front.

Comment: Sorted. I had removeFromSuperview in my hidePickerView method. Very careless. Done this quite a few times today, rushing and not reading my code line for line and thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the **hidden** property of the UIView subclass you are working with.

**Source:**
[UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden)

As far as your outlet being **nil** - make sure you have connected the IBOutlet to an actual element in the storyboard.